# First login fails after upgrading to 18.04 gdm3

Tags: 18.04, login, gdm

I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 and not like most of the threads I'm finding my first login attempt fails. Second time it works. I'm quite not sure where to look for the issue please help me out.

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: Just comes back to login. Where can I see any logs about this. So I can post it here?